# What is the simplest way to pass javascript object to asp.net codebehind method and parse it?

Tags: asp.net, json

I use PageMethods object to call a codebehind method in asp.net. I can send and receive parameters like string, int etc. But i must send a javaScript object to codeBehind. How can i parse the parameter and get data from codeBehind? I think i must use JSON parser but i wonder if there is an easy way, or if .net framework has Json parser (or like JSON) ?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function test(idParam, nameParam) {
            var jsonObj = { id: idParam, name: nameParam };

            PageMethods.testMethod(jsonObj,
                function (result) { alert(result) });
        }
    </script>
```

```cs
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string testMethod(object param)
    {
        int id = 1;//I must parse param and get id
        string name = "hakan"; //I must parse param and get name

        return "Id:" + id + "\n" + "Name:" + name + "\n" + "Date:" + DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you can add  System.Collections.Generic as a using clause to clean it up more):

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string testMethod(object param)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object> Collection;
    Collection = param as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object>;

    int id = (int) Collection["id"];
    string name = Collection["name"] as String;

    return "Id:" + id + "\n" + "Name:" + name + "\n" + "Date:" + DateTime.Now;
}
```

[Edit] Even simpler:

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
[WebMethod()]
public static string testMethod(Dictionary<String, Object> Collection)
{       
    int id = (int) Collection["id"];
    string name = Collection["name"] as String;

    return "Id:" + id + "\n" + "Name:" + name + "\n" + "Date:" + DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: ...Took me way longer than I hoped, but it's not your fault. I wanted to do this using an object with a list in it: `var jsonListOfStrings = {"listOfTexts": [] };` and when I read it back in with C# I was trying to parse it using a cast to `List<string>` or `string[]`, but it turns out you have to cast to `object[]` and then you can iterate through it. Hope that helps someone. Kudos.